# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common

Tags: unity-container

I have been using previous version of unity extension. Now I have to upgrade my project with a newer version of Unity Extension. 
I have code in my previous version as :-

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.AddNewExtensionIfNotPresent<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Interception>(Context.Container);
this.Context.Container.AddExtension(new ContainerRegistration());
```

But in new version Unity is not found under Configuration, has it moved to a new method?

Answer (score 0):

The Unity building block can be installed with NuGet. You can get more informations [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/), or by opening the package manager in Visual Studio and searching for Unity.

The class you're looking for are now in another namespace. For example, `UnityContainerExtensions` is in `Microsoft.Practices.Unity`. I'd recommend adding a `using` on top of the classes where you're dealing with the `UnityContainer` to simplify the reading.

Comment: I have used it. But new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common doesnot have AddNewExtensionIfNotPresent method in  latest release soI am getting error in this method. Any alternative for this method in latest version ?

Comment: @NitinKumar Edited answer.